# Does it need 'where' in "He wanted to explore the place the third brother had died."

Tags: sentence-construction

> "...... He wanted to come to Godric's Hollow, as I am sure you have guessed, because of the grave of Ignotus Peverell. **He wanted to explore the place the third brother had died.**" (Dumbledore)
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I think it should add 'where' there: *He wanted to explore the place **where** the third brother had died.*

It seems that 'where' is omissible in this case. I'm wondering under what circumstances it's omissible?

Comment: You might find it more useful to analyse this "sparse syntax" in terms of a missing *preposition (**in, at**)* rather than a missing *relative pronoun (**where, that**)*. Hence *This is the spot he died at, That's the chair he sat in, Here's the room I slept in.*.  The most common example I can think of is [This is the place it happened.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22is+the+place+it+happened%22) It may not be strictly "grammatical", but it's definitely ***idiomatic*** in certain contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica It seems that there isn't a kind of rule for it. We have to analyse it case by case, or simply by rote?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica So far, it seems to me that this omission is around the word *place*. *...the place it happened*, *...the place the third brother had died*. Any other words work for this?

Comment: *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Chapter 12, 3.5.4: https://i.imgur.com/7mhBXe3.png

Comment: Dan: For *spatial* "locatives", I think we're more able to discard the preposition (or relative pronoun) with words like ***place, spot, location*** (that *inherently* allude to "spatial coordinates"), rather than "objects" such as ***house, chair, bed***. But per @athlonusm's link, things are a lot more flexible with "location" in ***time*** rather than ***space***. No-one would have a problem with *We celebrate the day Christ was born, He remembered the day he first met her, I went out the moment it stopped raining*. Which are effectively the same syntax (but *chronological*, not spatial).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Is it still idiomatic when we add the preposition back? *We celebrate the day Christ was born in*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica I also found "the way", "the reason". *The way you look at it is different from the way I look at it.* *This is the reason you refused me*.

Comment: @athlonusm, I appreciate if you can turn that into an answer so that I can retrieve it in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to write you an answer. But never in this lifetime can I explain better than this answer: [When are relative pronouns omitted in a sentence?](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/283473/300322).

Comment: @AIQ, thanks! But I think we are talking about something different here. The one you link me in is mainly on the omission of 'that', 'which' and 'who', while what we are talking about here is the omission of 'where', 'when', 'why' which would only be applicable for certain kind of words, such as 'way', 'place',  'reason', etc.

Comment: @dan I thought it would be helpful at understanding these omissions at a much broader level. But perhaps this is narrow enough (see last paragraph): [Relative clauses after *place*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/297987/isnt-that-the-place-which-kids-under-12-cant-enter-is-it-correct-to-use/298061#298061).

Comment: @AIQ, Yeah, that's a direct answer to my question here particularly regarding 'place'. I have no difficult to understand the general omission of 'which', 'that', and 'who'. I'm more interested in the topic of some special cases, like the rules in the link by athlonusm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the chapter from *CGEL* I posted in the comments. I've also included a few units from *PEU* and a small selection of examples from COCA.

---

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Chapter 12, 3.5.4c:

> Relatives introduced by *when* or *why* have non-*wh* counterparts, with or without *that*:
>
> [60]
>   i *I haven’t seen them since the day [**when**/**(that)** Kim was born].*
>   ii *That’s the reason [**why**/**(that)** she resigned].*
>
> The notation ‘when/(that)’ indicates a choice between *when* and optional *that*, so we have *the day when Kim was born*, *the day that Kim was born*, or *the day Kim was born*. Relatives introduced by *where*, by contrast, do not in general alternate with the non-*wh* type except where the antecedent is a very general noun such as *place*:
>
> [61]
>   i *This is much better than the hotel [**where** we stayed last year].*
>   ii *This is much better than the place [**where**/**(<sup>?</sup>that)** we stayed last year].*
>
> The ‘<sup>?</sup>’ annotation in [ii] applies to the version with *that* (*<sup>?</sup>the place that we stayed last year*); the bare relative (*the place we stayed last year*) is more acceptable.<sup>7</sup>
>
> When the antecedent is *way*, in either the path or the means sense, we have non-*wh* relatives or *wh* relatives introduced by preposition + *which*:
>
> [62]
>   i *Go back the way [**(that)**/**by which** you came].*
>   ii *I admired the way [**(that)**/**in which** she handled the situation].*
>
> *How* does not belong to the class of relative words, so we cannot have **the way how she handled the situation*.<sup>8</sup> Note that if *way* is replaced by *manner* the non-*wh* construction is no longer possible: **the manner (that) she handled the situation*.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>7</sup> The restriction to *wh* relatives does not apply when *where* is complement to stranded *at*: *the hotel where/(that) we stayed at last year*. *Where ... at* seems to be a blend between *where* and *which ... at*; note that with *in* we can have *which* but not *where*: *the hotel which/*where we stayed in last year*.
>
> <sup>8</sup> Some non-standard dialects differ; hence the line *<sup>!</sup>It ain’t what you do, it’s the way how you do it* in a rock ‘n’ roll song.

---

*Practical English Usage*:

> ## (233.9) relative *when*, *where* and *why*
>
> *When* and *where* can introduce relative clauses after nouns referring to time and place. They are used in the same way as preposition + *which*.
>
> *I'll never forget the day **when** I first met you.* (= ... the day on which ...)
>   *Do you know a shop **where** I can find sandals?* (= ... a shop at which ...)
>
> *Why* is used in a similar way after *reason*.
>
> *Do you know the reason **why** she doesn't like me?* (= ... the reason for which ...)
>
> ## (554) place
>
> In an informal style, *place* can often be followed directly by an infinitive or relative clause, with no preposition or relative word.
>
> *I'm looking for **a place to live**.* (More formal:... *a place to live in* OR ... *a place in which to live*.)
>   *There's no **place to sit down**.*
>   *You remember the **place we had lunch**?* (= ... *the place (that) we had lunch at?* OR *the place where we had lunch?*)
>
> We do not use *a place where* before an infinitive.
>
> *I'm looking for **a place (where) I can** wash my clothes. / **a place to** wash my clothes.* (NOT ... *<strike>a place where to wash my clothes</strike>*.)
>
> ## (567) reason
>
> *Reason* can be followed by a clause beginning *why...* or *that...*.
>
> *The **reason why** I came here was to be with my family.*
>   *Do you know the **reason that** they’re closing the factory?*
>
> In an informal style, *why/that* is often left out.
>
> *The reason she doesn't like me is that I make her nervous.*
>
> ## (608) time
>
> In relative structures after *time*, *that* is often used instead of *when* in an informal style (or dropped).
>
> *Do you remember the time **(that) Freddy pretended to be a ghost**?*
>   *You can come up and see me any time **(that) you like**.*
>   *The first time **(that) I saw her**, my heart stopped.*
>
> ## (620) way
>
> In an informal style, we often say *the way (that)* instead of *the way in/by which*.
>
> *I don't like **the way (that)** you talk to me.*
>   *Let's go **the way (that)** we went yesterday.*

---

Here are a few examples from the Corpus of Contemporary American English ([COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)):

> From the **year** he was born, 1991, to the **year** he left for college, 2010.
>
> He checked into the hotel on the **day** he disappeared.
>
> I woke up at five in the morning, precisely the **hour** I had intended to get up.
>
> Sinatra was also close to John F. Kennedy during the **period** that Kennedy was running for the presidency.
>
> The cottage was three miles from the **place** he was born and ten miles from the chapel where they married.
>
> You had an exact memory of the **spot** he was buried, but that memory failed you, too.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to omit *where*, a preposition in the end could compensate for that, since *to die* is not a transitive verb (otherwise, it might even sound as if that brother 'dyed the place'): *... place the third brother died **at**.* An example from Dickens's *Bleak House*:

> Can you show me... the place he died **at**... and the place where he
>   was buried?

Comment: So, you're saying that the original sentence in the book is ungrammatical ? *He wanted to explore the place the third brother had died.*

Comment: Looks like such a simplification is acceptable, at least colloquially, for a character in a novel, since correctors in the publishing house didn't change it.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm eager to get an answer for it. BTW, I'm not the one who downvoted your answer. Sorry.