# When "that" = "which" and when "that" = "a preposition + which"?

Tags: prepositions, time, that-vs-which

My own sentences where "*that*" = "*which*":
**(1a)** *The forum **(that)** I posted this question is for English language learners*. — (I know it's) incorrect
**(1b)** *The forum **(that)** I posted this question **on** is for English language learners*. — (I know it's) correct
**(1c)** *The forum **which** I posted this question is for English language learners*. — (I know it's) incorrect
**(1d)** *The forum **which** I posted this question **on** is for English language learners*. — (I know it's) correct

from [wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-day-that-when.3483867/#post-17685749):
**(2a)** *It happened the day **(that)** the car accident took place*. — (where it's said that it's) correct
**(2b)** *It happened the day **(that)** the car accident took place **on***. — (where it's said that it's) incorrect
from [wordreference.com](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/the-day-that-when.3483867/#post-17687631):
**(2c)** *It happened the day **which** the car accident took place*. — (where it's said that it's) incorrect
**(2d)** *It happened the day **which** the car accident took place **on***. — (where it's said that it's) correct but less natural than (2a)

That is, the sentences with "*which*" are subject to the same rules:
(1с) & (2c) are both incorrect,
(1d) & (2d) are both correct.
But why are the sentences with "*that*" not subject to the same rules?:
(1a) is incorrect whereas (2a) is correct,
(1b) is correct whereas (2b) is incorrect.

It's said on "wordreference.com" that in (2a-d), for some reason, "*that*" ≠ "*which*" but "*that*" = "*on which*". To me it's a very strange and unclear explanation because I can't see any differences between (1a-d) and (2a-d) in terms of grammar.

Could you explain to me please the rule:
when "*that*" = "*which*" and  when "*that*" = "*on which*"?
Or more generally:
when "*that*" = "*which*" and  when "*that*" = "*some preposition + which*"?

Comment: I find 2b to be OK, though the "on " at the end is awkward. I would prefer *It happened **on** the day (that) the car accident took place*, and for this sentence an extra "on" at the end is definitely wrong.

Comment: Both (1d) and (2d) would be better as "The forum/day **on which**..." (without the later 'on').

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/233484/21520

Answer (score -1):

(1a) is incorrect because you can't say "I posted the question the forum" - you have to include **on**, even when the word order is changed.

Sentences about when something happened are a special case. We *can* say "The day the accident took place" without having to include **on which.** "The day that the accident took place on" sounds very awkward.

Comment: Note that we can say "It happened that day" or "It happened on that day".